# How replace all links inside local files from mirror web site

Tags: c#, html, .net, hyperlink

I download a lot of files from a web site in C# with WebClient() to my local directory.

Now I want to create a Console Application(no Web App) to replace all links inside all html pages to get a portable web site readable by anyone on any plateform (usb key, mobile, etc..), pages must be opened by any browsers and all link must be valid.

Link is typed like this:

site: http://www.domain.com

```
<a href="/fr/wol/b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/31/">xxx</a>
<a href="/fr/wol/b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/66/21#h=134:288-135:0">zzz</a>
<a href="/fr/wol/b/bc/r30/lp-f/1001060069/1026">yyy</a>
<a href="/fr/wol/b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/61/3#h=16:360-17:0">xxx1</a>
<a href="/fr/wol/dx/r30/lp-f/1001060064/30652">xxx1</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/fr/1001060064/30652">xxx1</a>
```

I don't want to have this kind of links:

```
<a href="file://C:/Users/Documents/Site/fr/wol/b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/31/">xxx</a>
```

because the entire web site must be located anywhere.

The goal is to have relative links like this: (this is just an example and it's not exact)

```
<a href="../../b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/31/">xxx</a>
<a href="../../b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/66/21#h=134:288-135:0">zzz</a>
<a href="../../../bc/r30/lp-f/1001060069/1026">yyy</a>
<a href="../../b/r30/lp-f/Rbi8/F/1995/61/3#h=16:360-17:0">xxx1</a>
<a href="../wol/1001060064/30652">xxx1</a>
```

Is anything exists in language .Net Windows Form or Console Application (non Web) C# to make these relative links quickly ?

Comment: Search for  HtmlAgilityPack tutorial - should give you good staring point to update the post to be more concrete - way too broad now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that's the answer:

```
Uri uri1 = new Uri(linkPage);
Uri uri2 = new Uri(linkParentPage);
Uri relativeUri = uri2.MakeRelativeUri(uri1);
string result = Uri.UnescapeDataString(relativeUri.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy and without error checking, but it should get you started.

```
public void EditWebPages()
{
    foreach(String file in Directory.GetFiles("INSERT_FILES_DIR"))
    {
        String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);
        for(int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
            lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(RegexGrab("href=\"(.*?)\"", lines[i]), "../../YOUR/RELATIVE/LINK/");
        File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
    }
}

public static String RegexGrab(String reg, String txt)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    Match match = regex.Match(txt);
    String str = match.Groups[1].ToString();
    return str;
}
```